# URL not encoding correctly from Laravel Job

Tags: php, laravel-5, urlencode, guzzle

Using guzzle in laravel 5.8 to make external API requests in my app. When I perform a request from a controller it works fine.

How ever when using the same code in a Job which I dispatch in a controller, I dont get the same results, I get an incorrect url.

Tried using a variety of url and utf8 encoding/decoding

```
$name = 'Cheeríos';
$this->httpClient->get("$baseUri/" . strtolower($name) . "/info")->getBody();
```

actual results of url, which leads to a 404 because its removed the í from the name

```
example.com/user/cheer%E3%ADos/info
```

expected

```
example.com/user/cheer%C3%ADos/info
or
example.com/user/cheeríos/info
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rawurlencode() on the string prior to strtolower() resolved the problem.

```
$this->httpClient->get("$baseUri/" . strtolower(rawurlencode($name)) . "/info")->getBody();
```